# How many times can I use a spell component pouch before having to purchase a new one?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, spell-components

Many of the spells in the Basic Rules indicate that they require material components.  For the components that don't have a specific cost (I tend to call these mundane components), the Basic Rules state that I can get the components from a Component Pouch.

> **Component Pouch.** A component pouch is a small, watertight leather belt pouch that has compartments to hold all the material components and other special items you need to cast your spells, except for those components that have a specific cost (as indicated in a spell’s description).

D&D Basic Rules v0.1 | Page 48

How many times can I cast spells using a Component Pouch as the source of my material components, before the pouch is empty?  (Or, having purchased a Component Pouch, do I now need to go out and source all of the material components I am going to need?)

RAW answers are preferable, but in the absence of those, working (tested) house-rules are acceptable.  If your answer is a house-rule, please make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Similar topic, different edition: [What is the point of a spell component pouch?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8721/9058)

Comment: Related: [Does a component pouch automatically contain components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148905/does-a-component-pouch-automatically-contain-components)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is on page 79 of the Basic Rules:

> ## Material (M)
>
> Casting some spells requires particular objects, specified in parentheses in the component entry. **A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in chapter 5) in place of the components specified for a spell.** But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.

Simply having the pouch is enough to cast spells with non-valuable, non-consumed material components. It is assumed that your wizard automatically manages to keep the pouch full of the various odds-and-ends he requires.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that generally, the components in a spell component pouch (i.e. ones without a listed cost) are not consumed by the spell, only required to cast it. So you wouldn't run out.