# Must a Cleric have a holy symbol to make use of Harness Divine Power?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

Harness Divine Power states (*TCoE p.30*):

> As a bonus action, **you touch your holy symbol**, utter a prayer, and regain one expended spell slot  [...]

Does this mean this ability can only be used provided the Cleric has a holy symbol? In the *Spellcasting* feature for Cleric's it says "*You **can** use a holy symbol,*[...]" which should mean they can cast spells with materials, they are not forced to use a holy symbol; if a player chooses to make a character that uses materials instead of a holy symbol, are they locked out of using this feature?

Comment: Related: "[Does Burning Hands really require touching thumbs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46603)" and "[Is there “flavor text” in D&D 5e spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012)"

Comment: Also related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107052/15991

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, and spellcasting is a different matter**

That class feature about channel divinity, not spellcasting. The text states you have to touch your holy symbol so that is what you must do. There are other examples in the rules where you need a specific item of value to accomplish something (eg. [identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify) requires a pearl worth at least 100 gold).

You won't be locked out of that class feature if you decide to cast spells using material components, you just need to have a holy symbol for when you use channel divinity in that way.

Of course you could ask your DM if you could forgo the need for a holy symbol in this case. Rule 0 does take precedence regardless of what the rules state.