# Are there any practical differences between a belt pouch and component pouch in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

I am generating a 5e high-elf rogue for Waterdeep Dragon Heist and have chosen Message, which requires small pieces of copper wire. I've bought 2.5 foot of copper wire, cut to inches.

I have a belt pouch, but no component pouch. I have 14gp and a component pouch costs 25gp.

Is there any practical or fun differences between pouches? Are there any reasons why I would require a component pouch over a belt pouch? Storywise, would there be any problems getting into debt or get caught lifting a component pouch?

Comment: Class/background equipment lists mention a "belt pouch", equipment list mention "component pouch". For pregenerated characters, the Dragonborn Sorcerer equipment list mentions both types of pouch separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## They are different.  A component pouch is specialized equipment.

**tl;dr** The rules specifically require a component pouch which is a listed peice of equipment different from a pouch.

### Rules specifically require a component pouch

The [material component](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM) aspect of casting a spell specifically calls out the use of an arcane focus or component pouch.

### Narrative explanation

Component pouch covers the cost of mundane components and does not require the caster to retrieve components from around their person (that might require [use an object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#UseanObject)) while casting it.

### Component pouch and pouch are different pieces of equipment

In the basic rules [adventuring equipment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#OtherAdventuringGear), a pouch is 5sp while a component pouch is 25 gp.  The component pouch takes the place of an arcane focus for a single classed spellcaster as elaborated on in the answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103539/what-is-the-difference-between-an-arcane-focus-and-a-component-pouch).

The regular pouch does not take the place of the arcane focus, nor does it supply the mundane (no specifically cost listed) components of spells.

### Can still cast [*message*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message) without the pouch.

Since the character directly owns the components, they can still cast the message spell.  A component pouch or focus can be used in place of mundane components.

> A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in “Equipment”) **in place of** the components specified for a spell.

#### Copper wire not consumed

The *message* spell does not state that the component of the spell is consumed, so a single short piece of wire should be sufficient for as many castings as you like.

Comment: Why wouldn't a regular pouch filled with components not work? You're still reaching in and selecting your component, no?

Comment: Component pouch does not require object interaction.  Also, saves the accounting for the individual cost of each mundane component.

Comment: [You still need to access the spell's material components with a free hand](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80271/does-a-wizard-need-to-hold-a-component-pouch-or-focus-in-one-hand-in-order-for-i/80272)

Comment: @NautArch holding onto something you're already holding does not cost you the object interaction on your turn.  The spell caster with a pouch could draw a weapon and cast a spell on the same turn.  The one without a pouch could not.

Comment: Where does it state that interacting with a component pouch bypasses the Use an Object? Or that not having a component pouch requires Use an Object to access the component?

Comment: And how did you determine the cost of non-valued components to get to 25gp?

Comment: @NautArch Good point.  The rules specifically require a spell component pouch or arcane focus by name.  I'll drop the homebrew stuff from my answer.

Answer (score 10):

## One is filled with components automatically and is watertight, the other is not

The [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#) lists under the Adventuring Gear:

> **Component Pouch**. A component pouch is a small, watertight leather belt pouch...

### Component pouches include components

The difference between the two is that the Component Pouch includes your components and is compartmentalized and watertight. It includes all components

> except for those components that have a specific cost (as indicated in a spell's description).

A regular pouch is only going to be a regular pouch and you'll have to go and get your components. The regular pouch entry also mentions the subset of itself, the component pouch:

> A compartmentalized pouch for holding spell components is called a component pouch (described earlier in this section).

### Once filled, they're the same thing

However, if you've gone to the trouble of finding all of your material components and put them in a standard pouch, you've effectively got a component pouch. However, should it get wet, your components may be ruined.

### Character Sheets

The [pregen character sheet](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets) has both pouch types. In this case, your character has both a filled component pouch and a second pouch.

Comment: That gear list has "Component pouch/25 gp/2 lb." and "Pouch/5 sp/1 lb."

Comment: The pouch description is distinct too: *Pouch*. A cloth or leather pouch can hold up to 20 sling bullets or 50 blowgun needles, among other things. A compartmentalized pouch for holding spell components is called a component pouch (described earlier in this section).

Comment: Nice, that would account for the price and weight difference.

Comment: Filling a regular pouch with components is not enough to turn it into a component pouch because the regular pouch is neither compartmentalized, nor watertight.

Comment: Copper wire is pretty resistant to water damage

Answer (score 3):

### The Component Pouch comes with the components.

The belt pouch is just a pouch. There is no need to buy the component pouch if you have the components already. This isn't a video game, where there is a quantitative difference between a component pouch and a pouch with components in it. It's just that when one entry lists component pouch, it comes with the components. If it is a belt pouch, it is just an empty pouch. So you could in play buy a belt pouch, put all the common components in it, then sell it as a component pouch, because that's exactly what it is. A belt pouch someone put components in and sold for 25gp.

Comment: Are all pouches small, watertight, leather belt like, and have with compartments?