# Do warlocks require alchemist's supplies to cast healing elixir?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, spellcasting, spell-components

I play a Celestial Warlock in a campaign we just started, who took *healing elixir* ([link to Unearthed Arcana document](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf)) as one of his first spells to support our party. I plan to expand into Divine Soul Sorcerer later. My build would be 14-ish levels in Warlock and the rest in Sorcerer.

The components for *healing elixir* are:

> **Components:** V, S, M (alchemist's supplies)

So we participated in our first major battle against a bandit raid while we protected a caravan, after which I tried to cast *healing elixir*. My GM asked me if I have any Alchemist's supplies on me, to which I reply "no," but I have my focus which replaces any material components that spells don't specify with a gold cost.

His rebuttal is that since Alchemist's supplies themselves have a cost, I still need to have them, but the spell doesn't state their cost in the spell description.

I'm kind of at a loss about how I should respond to this or whether I am behaving overly concerned. We are only a level 2 party verging on level 3 now, so I am considering just scrapping this spell entirely.

**Does *healing elixir* actually require alchemist's supplies to cast, or does my focus allow me to ignore them?**

Comment: Related: "[Can a focus replace a material component if it doesn't state a value in the component list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138808)" and "[Do I need to hold an actual copper piece in order to cast the Detect Thoughts spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122661)". Actually, does the first question there answer yours?

Comment: @AlucardForever I have edited your question to focus more on what I think is your core problem. Can you confirm this is the question you wanted to ask? If so I'll be happy to reopen this for you.

Comment: So this has been closed a duplicate of another question. If that doesn't resolve the issue for you, do please clarify for us how this is different and we'll see what needs to be done to help.

Comment: Actually, not sure it's actually gonna be relevant, but where is *healing elixir* from? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Someone_Evil It’s a [UA from 2017](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for helping me answer this question. And yes this has helped massively. Hopefully when I get back to game my GM will understand.