# Where might one find copper wire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components

The [Message](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message) spell requires a short piece of copper wire to cast. Suppose you do not have access to a spell component pouch. Where might copper wire exist? And how might it be used outside of spellcasting?

Edit: In response to the comments below:

My character is on an island far from civilization. I just gained level 3 rogue and chose Arcane Trickster. I have no spell component pouch. So, when choosing cantrips, those without material components topped my list. Next, I was looking at those with components that would be easy to find.

My DM questioned why the message spell even had copper wire as a component, and decided that in his campaign, copper wire is not a thing. He replaced it with a material component that made more sense for his campaign.

But it got me wondering, where would you find it in a normal campaign? From what I know of copper wire, it is used for electrical wires. I am not aware of electrical wires in many DnD settings, so I assume the component would have other uses. If copper wire were not a thing, why would a spellcaster ever hold onto it in the first place to discover it was a material component? I suppose I was hoping for some sort of explanation from the designers about how they chose material components, or perhaps where they suspected material components could be found.

It is actually a moot point for my current character's situation, since the DM already removed the copper wire as a material component. I was asking about a normal campaign where copper wire is the required component for the Message spell. It is not really a problem I was trying to solve, but more of a curiosity.

From the comments, it appears this is entirely opinion-based, and there is no source for where to find components. DMs must come up with that. Since that is the answer, I am satisfied, and this question can be closed or deleted.

Comment: Wherever your DM says it does. Seriously though, this isn't exactly something we can answer *because* it's going to depend on the setting or world the DM runs and asking for all the possible ways copper wire could be used outside of spellcasting is both far too broad and also opinion-based. Aside from that, What circumstance lead you to ask this question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because open ended idea generation is off topic

Comment: I looked in just the first five pages of tags and found crafting, campaign development, and world building.  I don't think the question is off-topic for the site.  I _do_ think the OP has to better define what is the problem and why this information is needed so as to get quality answers.

Comment: This might be more along the lines of what you’re looking for: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94751/medieval-wire-making

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Your comment is actually the useful answer to this. I'm voting to reopen and recommend you convert you comment into an answer.

Comment: Related, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8726/9671

Comment: @Wyrmwood That is a better answer to this question and many more regarding spell components. Thank you for that.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe You are welcome. Yes, the history *strongly* suggests they shouldn't really be taken that seriously, nor should their availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you could go to a metal forger with raw cooper and ask him to make thin wire. There could also be intratic jewelry which has wire as part of the design. But ultimately it is **DM choice** and so you can ask him where you could make a makeshift copper wire. Either it be the options mentioned above or even the corpses of constructs or wizards without a arcane focus.